# Bad implementation of Enumerable.Single?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, algorithm

I came across this implementation in Enumerable.cs by reflector.

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    //check parameters
    TSource local = default(TSource);
    long num = 0L;
    foreach (TSource local2 in source)
    {
        if (predicate(local2))
        {
            local = local2;
            num += 1L;
            //I think they should do something here like:
            //if (num >= 2L) throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch();
            //no necessary to continue
        }
    }
    //return different results by num's value
}
```

I think they should break the loop if there are more than 2 items meets the condition, why they always loop through the whole collection? In case of that reflector disassembles the dll incorrectly, I write a simple test:

```
class DataItem
{
   private int _num;
   public DataItem(int num)
   {
      _num = num;
   }
    
   public int Num
   {
      get{ Console.WriteLine("getting "+_num); return _num;}
   }
} 
var source = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select( x => new DataItem(x));
var result = source.Single(x => x.Num < 5);
```

For this test case, I think it will print "getting 0, getting 1" and then throw an exception. But the truth is, it keeps "getting 0... getting 10" and throws an exception.
Is there any algorithmic reason they implement this method like this?

**EDIT** Some of you thought it's because of *side effects of the predicate expression*, after a deep thought and some test cases, I have a conclusion that **side effects doesn't matter in this case**. Please provide an example if you disagree with this conclusion.

**12 YEARS LATER** It's 2023 and I came across that the implementation is changed to the correct way in latest .NET :) https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Single.cs

Comment: @The Smartest: See my "by hand" decoding to C#

Comment: @The Smartest: You should use First or FirstOrDefault instead, it is expected by the BCL writers, i believe

Comment: Mr. Crazy went through this question and downvoted all answers...

Comment: Enumerable.cs is part of System.Linq which is in System.Core.dll, part of the BCL.  Is this library released under a permissive license or is it proprietary? I believe (but I'm not 100% sure) that it is proprietary.  Please don't post proprietary code - people who read this cant' contribute to projects like Mono.

Comment: @Michael: A very interesting point.  Is the decompilation of a method covered under copyright?  In any case, this has already been implemented in Mono.  I'm interested in hearing an answer from a lawyer on this one.

Comment: @Michael: Hm.  It looks like the BCL has been released by Microsoft under the Microsoft Reference License.  Never heard of it.

Comment: Well, he's not even posting the methods implementation as decompiled; this is an edited version highlighting the odd behavior: it's an extremely short rephrased quote, if you will - I doubt it's an issue.

Comment: 'The Microsoft Reference Source License (MS-RSL) is the most restrictive of the Microsoft source code licenses. The license prohibits all use of source code other than the viewing of the code for reference purposes. The intent of this license is to enable licensors to release, for review purposes only, more sensitive intellectual property assets.'  - Yeah I'd say it's a problem.  @Eamon - even so, because we've seen bits of it, it could be argued that our implementation of it in Mono was based off protected materials.

Comment: @yodaj007 - Yes it has been implemented in Mono, but that wasn't based on looking at the MS source code (unless this area has been freely released, in which case it might just be a direct drop in as is the case with other areas such as MVC).

Comment: @Michael: But if its already been implemented in Mono, what is the danger of posting it here, now?  Note that I didn't say Mono had used BCL source - only that it has been.  IANAL.  I find this issue really fascinating and am eager to see the discussion of it continued, perhaps in another SO question.

Comment: @Michael: isn't posting this code with a question considered *for review purposes*? and thus legal according to the license? Still, the code is not a copied and used in software. I highly doubt this is a legal issue. The whole of SO would probably fall apart if it were :)

Comment: @The Smartest: Curious, how did you find this?

Comment: @yodaj007: By accident, I like looking into built-in libraries via reflector in my spare time. LOL.

Comment: @Michael: this isn't based on the MS-RSL license, it's based on the binary.  Indeed, even if it were, it's irrelevant: whatever terms it has are contract terms for the licensee - not some third party such as mono - they don't even have *any* license, most likely.  Given the extent and the rephrasing and selection and the minute scope - it's hard to argue this is relevant.  I seriously doubt mono & microsoft will ever face each other in a courtroom based on the non-patented implementation of an obvious, trivial and very short algorithm, so let's not get carried away here...

Comment: I'm not even sure if this is proprietary or not :) @Peter - yeah I don't think there is any issue with looking at it for reference, but contributors to Mono aren't allowed to look at it since it is hard to not let it influence your implementation in Mono.  Nothing wrong with non-contributors looking at it (I think), just suggesting people don't post it here so that contributors would be able to help them.  Not a huge issue at all.  (I'm not a lawyer, don't know if any of this is correct).

Comment: Aside: turns out mono doesn't have this issue: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs it uses the same implementation for the predicate and predicate-less overloads :-) - which is exactly what MS should have done in the first place...

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: You are wrong, since MS implemenmtaion for the Single<TSource> follows my answer, and differs Mono version, I'm actually disassembled the System.Core.dll. I suppose that Mono implemenmtation is the right one, but that differences in behavioral is not mentioned in CLI standarts, so MS version still seems correct for me. Cheers ;)

Comment: I don't understand - why is the assertion that it is because of the predicate's side-effects not good enough? If that predicate has side-effects, you'd want them to happen on the whole list, not only to an unknown number of its elements. The Single() overload stops as soon as possible because there are no side-effects.

Comment: Amazingly, `SingleOrDefault()` has the same issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, I do find it slightly strange especially because the overload that doesn't take a predicate (i.e. works on just the sequence) *does* seem to have the quick-throw 'optimization'.

---

In the BCL's defence however, I would say that the **InvalidOperation exception that Single throws is a [boneheaded exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) that shouldn't normally be used for control-flow.** It's not necessary for such cases to be optimized by the library.

Code that uses `Single` where zero or multiple matches is a perfectly *valid* possibility, such as:

```
try
{
     var item = source.Single(predicate);
     DoSomething(item);
}

catch(InvalidOperationException)
{
     DoSomethingElseUnexceptional();    
}
```

should be refactored to code that *doesn't* use the exception for control-flow, such as (only a sample; this can be implemented more efficiently):

```
var firstTwo = source.Where(predicate).Take(2).ToArray();

if(firstTwo.Length == 1) 
{
    // Note that this won't fail. If it does, this code has a bug.
    DoSomething(firstTwo.Single()); 
}
else
{
    DoSomethingElseUnexceptional();
}
```

---

In other words, we should leave the use of `Single` to cases when we expect the sequence to contain *only* one match.  It should behave identically to `First`but with the additional **run-time assertion** that the sequence doesn't contain multiple matches. Like any other assertion, **failure, i.e. cases when `Single` throws, should be used to represent bugs in the program** (either in the method running the query or in the arguments passed to it by the caller).

This leaves us with two cases:

1. The assertion holds: There is a single match. In this case, we want `Single` to consume the entire sequence *anyway* to assert our claim. There's no benefit to the 'optimization'. In fact, one could argue that the sample implementation of the 'optimization' provided by the OP will actually be slower because of the check on every iteration of the loop.
2. The assertion fails: There are zero or multiple matches. In this case, we *do* throw later than we *could*, but this isn't such  a big deal since the exception is boneheaded: **it is indicative of a bug that must be fixed.**

To sum up, if the 'poor implementation' is biting you performance-wise in production, either:

1. You are using `Single` incorrectly.
2. You have a bug in *your* program. Once the bug is fixed, this particular performance problem will go away.

EDIT: Clarified my point.

EDIT: Here's a *valid* use of Single, where failure indicates bugs in the *calling* code (bad argument):

```
public static User GetUserById(this IEnumerable<User> users, string id)
{
     if(users == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("users");

     // Perfectly fine if documented that a failure in the query
     // is treated as an exceptional circumstance. Caller's job 
     // to guarantee pre-condition.        
     return users.Single(user => user.Id == id);    
}
```

Comment: While I do agree that the user's code should be fixed, there's no sane reason to me why a library method should not fail as soon as possible when it can do so with no extra effort.  This seems like a trivial thing to me.

Comment: @Jeff M: It's not meant to fail - a failure is a **bug**. When it doesn't fail, it performs *faster* without the 'optimization'.

Comment: @Ani: Fail may have been the wrong word to describe it, perhaps "report the error", but still...

Comment: I disagree: the method is documented to throw an exception by design when there are duplicate predicate matches.  Writing your code according to the intended design of the method isn't a bug in your code.

Comment: @yodaj007: How does my post contradict that?

Comment: @Ani: Fair argument there.  Ya got me.  :)

Comment: I believe that Single must not duplicate First or FirstOrDefault extension methods

Comment: I disagree with the refactoring. IMO it obstructs the code's true meaning: Using the `Single` operator expresses one's assumption that the sequence must contain exactly one item. I believe the `Single` method is only appropriate when you're certain that this is the only possible outcome. If an exception is thrown, it'll mean that *your program's logic* contains a bug. In cases where a collection could *possibly* contain more than one item (e.g. when dealing with I/O input, which should never be considered reliable), `Single` is inappropriate because you need to perform validation first anyway.

Comment: @Ani: You are completely wrong, because that single Single version is applied to the IQueryable<TSource> source, not IEnumerable<TSource> one, and we are speaking about IEnumerable<TSource> extensions method

Comment: @Artur Mustafin: No, I just rechecked.

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for the clarification, took me a while to get your point with what you had originally.

Comment: @Ani: You're saying the exception being thrown is a bug in the users code.  If the user is coding his application according to the documentation of the method, it isn't a bug.  It *is*, however, a misuse of exceptions - being used for logic, that is.

Comment: @Ani: I don't think so. Whether or not you need to validate your collection before calling `Single` depends on what kind of collection we're talking about, and what kinds of guarantees your program logic can make about that collection. See my answer for more details.

Comment: I would imagine this is the correct answer. Throwing late is optimised for the success case which seems fair as (a) Single is basically First with an assertion that it is the only one and assertions are expected to succeed, and (b) SEH is painfully slow so there is rarely a point to optimising a path that always results in an exception being thrown.

Comment: "the overload that doesn't take a predicate (i.e. works on just the sequence) does seem to have the quick-throw 'optimization'"  - the overload without a predicate doesn't iterate over the enumeration - hence the question of this "optimisation" doesn't arise.  The current implementation is correct IMHO as it optimises for the expected case where the enumeration contains exactly one match - see my answer.

Comment: +1. Changed my mind: This is a good answer. The "refactoring" shown still isn't pretty code, but as a way to drive home the main point it does well enough.

Comment: Your argument only applies to `Single`, but the question applies equally to `SingleOrDefault`, so you’re back to square one.

Comment: @Timwi: There's just a weaker assertion at play there: 0 or 1 elements. If you hit an exception there, it's still meant to represent a bug.

Comment: @Ani: I think you are confused, but I don’t know where. Maybe you don’t know what `SingleOrDefault` does? It does the same thing as `Single`; the only difference is that it returns the default value instead of throwing, irrespective of whether there are 0 or more than 1 matching elements.

Comment: @Timwi: I am not confused, but I do think you have misunderstood `SingleOrDefault`. It returns the single match when there is only one, the default when there are no matches, and **throws** when there are multiple matches. I think you have not considered the last point. I suggest you try `var a = new[] {1,1,2}.SingleOrDefault(x => x == 1);` or similar, or read up on the [**`Enumerable.SingleOrDefault** method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549274.aspx). It is true of both the predicate and vanilla variants.

Comment: @Ani: Indeed; so it was me that was confused. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Single(predicate) is about a combination of Where() Count()==1 and First(). It can simply code logic.

Comment: This argument doesn't hold. Indeed, this is a good example of the general principle that upon detecting an exception the only thing you should do before throwing is clean up resources (which a fixed version would do faster - rather than tie up a database or network connection if the enumeration is based on one).
As you say, there being more than 2 matching elements is an error condition; things have not gone as expected. Causes of more matching elements than expected will overlap with causes of more elements than expected. If the exception was caused by the sequence failing to iterate...

Comment: ...and being in an infinite loop; the correct version of this code will throw quickly with an exception that will lead a developer to the problem quickly. This version however will tie up a thread (and any resources used by the enumeration) for hours before either this method throws an `OverflowException` (which it is not documented as ever throwing), or with a bit of luck something feeding the enumeration times out (though that may not even have a chance to trigger it's own exception depending on what is leading to the bug). It's also doing slightly more work than needed in the normal case.

Comment: Is moving the check to the end really an optimization of the "normal" case?  If there's one matching item in the list, a check which is performed as each matching item is found to ensure it is the first one will be performed exactly once.  At worst, the code would have to replace two "test if number is exactly one" tests with "test if number is non-zero".  Since one could replace `num+=1;` with `num=1`, I really don't see any decisive speed advantage either way.

Comment: @supercat Not to mention that there's no need to check the number found at all; if rather than think of it as "two or more" one thinks of it as "found after the result was found" the logic changes to scanning to until a match is found, and then scanning through the rest and throwing if another match is found (as per my answer), removing the need for any tally at all.

Comment: @JonHanna: Using separate loops for "find first item" and "check for more" might speed things up, but might also make the code a little bigger; the costs of that could (due to cache-related effects) potentially outweigh the performance gains.  In any case, there's no performance-related justification for the way `Single` is coded (since fail-on-second-match would almost certainly not be *measurably* worse than fail-at-end); the only question would be whether exhausting the input stream on failure would be considered desirable behavior.

Comment: @supercat Not the only question. The undocumented behaviour of throwing OverflowException is another question.

Comment: @JonHanna: Endless input streams are not exactly rare; from a practical standpoint having an `OverflowException` thrown is probably better than hanging, though the fact that it's thrown when there are about 2^31 excess matches, as opposed to when there are over 2^31 list items, means that only some endless loops will be averted.  Too bad there isn't any way for an `IEnumerable` to report whether it's finite with known bound, finite with unknown bound, infinite, or could be anything.

Comment: @supercat someone calling `Single()` on an endless enumerable should be rare, because by definition it can't ever be useful. Any such case is a clear error either in the call, or in the enumerable, but either way the sooner it fails, the better.

Comment: @JonHanna: I agree that it's better for things to fail sooner than later; that's why I wish endless sequences could report themselves as such.  Imagine that one has some enumerables which implement `ISnapshotEnumerable`, with inherits `Enumerable` but also includes a `Snapshot` method.  An endless sequence may be able to support `ISnapshotEnumerable` very cheaply, and one could have a `Snapshot` extension method that would work with all enumerables that implement `ISnapshotEnumerable` as well as all reasonable-length sequences (using `ToArray`), but...

Comment: ...would fail on endless sequences that don't support the snapshot method.  If a method can't possibly work on endless sequences, it would be much better for it to fail immediately than for it to gobble up huge amount of memory (probably including some major LOH allocations) in an effort that's guaranteed to fail.  I wonder if MS will ever define a standard way for enumerables to supply information about themselves?

Answer (score 7):

> ***Update:**
>
>   I got some very good feedback to my answer, which has made me re-think. Thus I will first provide the answer that states my "new" point of view; you can still find my original answer just below. Make sure to read the comments in-between to understand where my first answer misses the point.*

## New answer:

Let's assume that `Single` should throw an exception when it's pre-condition is not met; that is, when `Single` detects than either none, or more than one item in the collection matches the predicate.

`Single` can only succeed without throwing an exception by going through the whole collection. It has to make sure that there is exactly one matching item, so it will have to check all items in the collection.

This means that throwing an exception early (as soon as it finds a second matching item) is essentially an optimization that you can only benefit from when `Single`'s pre-condition cannot be met and when it will throw an exception.

As user CodeInChaos says clearly in a comment below, the optimization wouldn't be wrong, but it is meaningless, because one usually introduces optimizations that will benefit correctly-working code, not optimizations that will benefit malfunctioning code.

Thus, it is actually correct that `Single` could throw an exception early; but it doesn't have to, because there's practically no added benefit.

---

## Old answer:

I cannot give a technical reason *why* that method is implemented the way it is, since I didn't implement it. But I can state my understanding of the `Single` operator's *purpose*, and from there draw my personal conclusion that it is indeed badly implemented:

### My understanding of `Single`:

**What is the purpose of `Single`, and how is it different from e.g. `First` or `Last`?**

Using the `Single` operator basically expresses one's assumption that exactly one item must be returned from the collection:

- If you don't specify a predicate, it should mean that the collection is expected to contain exactly one item.
- If you do specify a predicate, it should mean that exactly one item in the collection is expected to satisfy that condition. (Using a predicate should have the same effect as  `items.Where(predicate).Single()`.)

This is what makes `Single` different from other operators such as `First`, `Last`, or `Take(1)`. None of those operators have the requirement that there should be *exactly* one (matching) item.

**When should `Single` throw an exception?**

Basically, when it finds that your assumption was wrong; i.e. when the underlying collection does *not* yield exactly one (matching) item. That is, when there are zero or more than one items.

**When should `Single` be used?**

The use of `Single` is appropriate when your program's logic can guarantee that the collection will yield exactly one item, and one item only. If an exception gets thrown, that should mean that your program's logic contains a bug.

If you process "unreliable" collections, such as I/O input, you should first validate the input before you pass it to `Single`. `Single`, together with an exception `catch` block, is *not* appropriate for making sure that the collection has only one matching item. By the time you invoke `Single`, you should *already* have made sure that there'll be only one matching item.

### Conclusion:

The above states my understanding of the `Single` LINQ operator. If you follow and agree with this understanding, you should come to the conclusion that **`Single` ought to throw an exception as early as possible**. There is no reason to wait until the end of the (possibly very large) collection, because the pre-condition of `Single` is violated as soon as it detects a second (matching) item in the collection.

Comment: But since the case where it throws an exception is the case where your program has a bug, performance in this case doesn't matter much.

Comment: I agree that it would be *nice* if the algorithm *could* throw as early as possible. Still, I fail to see how you can implement that and guarantee that your algorithm will be faster *in all possible scenarios*.

Comment: *@CodeInChaos:* Imagine you have an infinite sequence: `IEnumerable<int> xs() { while (true) { yield 1; } }`. Now you call `xs().Single(x => x > 0);` You will wait forever. Wouldn't it be nicer to get an exception? (Note that the code shown doesn't make sense. Just take my code as a placeholder for some code that actually contains a logic bug. In reality, you wouldn't wait forever, but you might run into cases where you have to wait very long until you get an exception.)

Comment: *@Peter Lillevold:* IMHO, execution speed is not as relevant here as fulfilling the right contract. Especially because we're very likely talking about a micro-optimisation here (an additional `if` in an inner loop, and the `if` can be as simple as checking whether a boolean variable has the value `false` or `true`; something which can be done with one CIL opcode: `brfalse` a.k.a. `brzero`).

Comment: @stakx I'm not opposed to that optimization. I'm just stating that it's irrelevant in practice. And in your infinite sequence `Single` won't terminate in the non exception case either. And that can't be optimized out.

Comment: @Peter About the performance hit of the additional check: It's not an additional `if` in an inner loop. It's an additional `if` in a codeblock that will execute at most two times. So performance hit is `O(1)` and very small.

Comment: @stakx: I agree, speed is not a priority, contract is. That is where I disagree with introducing the `if`-optimization. Because it would be an optimization that suits only some scenarios but not every scenario. That is why I argue in my answer that optimization should only be considered when performance tests shows a bottleneck. If `Single` shows up to be the bad guy, throw it out and implement something better.

Comment: @stakx: but I will not downvote you, just because I *disagree*, or because I think my answer is *better* than yours. I will only not give you a vote ... this time :)

Comment: @stakx: -1. Single could not throw an exceptions as early as possible, because if it will finds a single match at the early first element, who garanteed, that second element will not be the last one in collection? So it CAN NOT EXITS searching algorithm until it finishes, overwize you should check for a count of already found items inside a loop, on every cycle, which is not very efficient, because of the big overhead on a big collections

Comment: *@CodeInChaos*: Well said. I can now see both yours and Peter's point. +1. *@Peter*: You're right, this seems to come down to a matter of what exactly `Single` is supposed to mean, and people can disagree there. So thanks for not downvoting :-D, and for your opinion on this. I appreciate both your feedback!

Comment: *@Artur:* That's not how I meant it. Breaking off early certainly is possible: Indeed it cannot stop after finding only one match, but it *certainly* could when it finds the second match. For example, if you have a sequence of 100 items, and both the 1st and 6th items match, then you could stop after the 6th instead of iterating over the remaining 94 items. **But** I would now take CodeInChaos' and Peter Lillevold's stance that breaking early is an optimisation that benefits only the error case.

Comment: @stakx: You present the early exit as an "optimization":  I view the reimplementation of `.Single` in two virtually identical ways a bad case of copy-paste coding.  Why isn't `.Single(predicate)` just `.Where(predicate).Single()`?  Why does single's behavior change wrt to execution time and side-effects depending on overload?  Indeed, the current version isn't even any shorter.  It's just sometimes slower, copy-pasted but with slightly different semantics.

Comment: Actually, there is another reason, why Single implemented like I described: Single designed to return the single match of a sequence, otherwise the last one, if you will break the look as soon as possible, how would you know if that particular match is the really the last one (until you go to the end)?

Comment: *@Artur:* You've already repeatedly been shown to be wrong on this particular point, so why still insist on it? `Single` does *not* exhibit the behaviour of `Last` (like you wrongfully claim it does) when there are several matches. If there is more than one match (or none), it throws an exception [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx). So your latest argument against breaking early doesn't hold. (And just as a suggestion; but I won't insist on it: Since your downvote to my answer is based on a clearly wrong assumption, why not undo the downvote?)

Comment: This argument only applies to `Single`, but the question equally applies to `SingleOrDefault`, so you’re back to square one.

Answer (score 4):

When considering this implementation we must remember that this is the BCL: general code that is supposed to work good *enough* in all sorts of scenarios.

First, take these scenarios:

1. Iterate over 10 numbers, where the first and second elements are equal
2. Iterate over 1.000.000 numbers, where the first and third elements are equal

The original algorithm will work well enough for 10 items, but 1M will have a severe waste of cycles. So in these cases *where we know* that there are two or more early in the sequences, the proposed optimization would have a nice effect.

Then, look at these scenarios:

1. Iterate over 10 numbers, where the first and last elements are equal
2. Iterate over 1.000.000 numbers, where the first and last elements are equal

In these scenarios the algorithm is still required to inspect every item in the lists. There is no shortcut. The original algorithm will perform good *enough*, it fulfills the contract. Changing the algorithm, introducing an `if` on each iteration will actually *decrease* performance. For 10 items it will be negligible, but 1M it will be a big hit.

IMO, the original implementation is the correct one, since it is good enough for most scenarios. Knowing the implementation of `Single` is good though, because it enables us to make smart decisions based on what we know about the sequences we use it on. If performance measurements in one particular scenario shows that `Single` is causing a bottleneck, well: then we can implement our own variant that works better *in that particular scenario*.

**Update:** as [CodeInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445517/codeinchaos) and [Eamon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825401/bad-implementation-of-enumerable-single/4826772#4826772) have correctly pointed out, the `if` test introduced in the optimization is indeed **not** performed on each item, only within the predicate match block. I have in my example completely overlooked the fact that the proposed changes will not affect the overall performance of the implementation.

I agree that introducing the optimization would probably benefit all scenarios. It is good to see though that eventually, the decision to implement the optimization is made on the basis of performance measurements.

Comment: I disagree: I believe that Single must not duplicate First or FirstOrDefault extension methods in BCL

Comment: @Artur Mustafin -  what? downvoted?? And where do I state that `Single` is or should be a duplicate of `First` ??

Comment: +1 Neat theory; that this would be more efficient in the normal case (i.e. the correct case).  But that's not born out in my quick test: I tried `Enumerable.Range(0,100000000).Single(x=>x==123)` and `Enumerable.Range(0,100000000).Where(x=>x==123).Single()` and the latter is slightly *faster*.

Comment: @Eamon: very interesting. Perhaps since the latter is not doing 100M increments... and again, only performance measurements in each particular case shows whether to optimize or not :)

Comment: @Peter: the latter must do all the increments - after all, even the plain single implementation checks at least 2 elements, and to attempt to generate 2 elements `Where` will need to iterate over the entire sequence.  (detail: since the queries take more than a second to run, I assume the optimizer isn't being supersmart and realizing that the single element must be 123 - and given the presence of delegates and interfaces, that would be a truly impressive feat of optimization anyhow.)

Comment: @Peter, you didn't downvote me, but let me upvote you. (Btw. I changed my answer. Maybe you'll agree with it now?)

Comment: @stakx: indeed, your new conclusion is a +1.

Comment: Although it has already been pointed out that the `if` would only happen in the predicate match block, I would also like to point out that an `if` would probably be faster than `n++`, which is what it does right now.

Comment: There's no need to test the number found at all, rather than keep the `num` of the buggy implementation, just go into a new loop while `MoveNext()` returns true, and throw on a match.

Comment: The `if` would only need to happen on those iterations where `num` was changed.  Since it would only be executed at most once in cases where the function isn't supposed to throw, and would be beneficial in all cases where it would be executed more than twice, I can't imagine any realistic cases where it should pose any measurable slowdown whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a premature optimization "bug".

### Why this is NOT reasonable behavior due to side effects

Some have argued that due to side effects, it should be expected that the entire list is evaluated.  After all, in the correct case (the sequence indeed has just 1 element) it is completely enumerated, and for consistency with this normal case it's nicer to enumerate the entire sequence in *all* cases.

Although that's a reasonable argument, it flies in the face of the general practice throughout the LINQ libraries: they use lazy evaluation everywhere.  It's *not* general practice to fully enumerate sequences except where absolutely necessary; indeed, several methods prefer using `IList.Count` when available over any iteration at all - even when that iteration may have side effects.

Further, `.Single()` *without* predicate does not exhibit this behavior: that terminates as soon as possible.  If the argument were that `.Single()` should respect side-effects of enumeration, you'd expect all overloads to do so equivalently.

### Why the case for speed doesn't hold

Peter Lillevold made the interesting observation that it may be faster to do...

```
foreach(var elem in elems)
    if(pred(elem)) {
        retval=elem;
        count++;
    }
if(count!=1)...
```

than

```
foreach(var elem in elems)
    if(pred(elem)) {
        retval=elem;
        count++;
        if(count>1) ...
    }
if(count==0)...
```

After all, the second version, which would exit the iteration as soon as the first conflict is detected, would require an extra test in the loop - a test which in the "correct" is purely ballast.  Neat theory, right?

Except, that's not bourne out by the numbers; for example on my machine (YMMV) `Enumerable.Range(0,100000000).Where(x=>x==123).Single()` is actually *faster* than `Enumerable.Range(0,100000000).Single(x=>x==123)`!

It's possibly a JITter quirk of this precise expression on this machine - I'm not claiming that `Where` followed by predicateless `Single` is always faster.

But whatever the case, the fail-fast solution is very unlikely to be significantly slower.  After all, even in the normal case, we're dealing with a cheap branch: a branch that is *never* taken and thus easy on the branch predictor.  And of course; the branch is further only ever encountered when pred holds - that's once per call in the normal case.  That cost is simply negligible compared to the cost of the delegate call `pred` and its implementation, *plus* the cost of the interface methods `.MoveNext()` and `.get_Current()` and their implementations.

It's simply extremely unlikely that you'll notice the performance degradation caused by one predictable branch in comparison to all that other abstraction penalty - not to mention the fact that most sequences and predicates actually do something themselves.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote. That extra test will be *hit only once* in the non throwing case, and not on each loop iteration. And as you said its cost is vanishing compared to a delegate call. And the logic after the loop can be simplified if you already check that case inside the loop and the int counter replaced by a bool. So I don't think the additional check slows the success case down in any significant way, but provided large benefits in the failure case. So I'd use the early out.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: yep.  Added a sentence pointing out it's only hit once.

Comment: It's obvoius, that .Where() is faster than .Single(), since .Where() does no count its matches, and it has one comparison less and local variable less and one increment oiperation less than in  a .Single(), so .Where() is actually faster than .Single(), because you can get .Where() has shorter inner-loop cycle

Comment: @Artur `Where(pred).Single()` and `Single(pred)` are semantically equivalent, so `Single(pred)` should be at least as fast as `Where(pred).Single()`, and possibly even a bit faster. So once again you're not making any sense.

Answer (score 2):

It seems very clear to me.

`Single` is intended for the case where the caller knows that the enumeration contains exactly one match, since in any other case an expensive exception is thrown.

For this use case, the overload that takes a predicate must iterate over the whole enumeration.  It is slightly faster to do so without an additional condition on every loop.

In my view the current implementation is correct: it is optimized for the expected use case of an enumeration that contains exactly one matching element.

Comment: ...there isn't any extra condition on every iteration of the loop body - only those where the predicate matches: i.e. once.

Comment: Actually, there is another readon, why Single implemented like I described: Silgle defsigned to return the single match of a sequence, otherwise the last one, if you will break the look as soon as possible, how would you know if that particular match is the really the last one (untill you go to the end)?

Answer (score 1):

That does appear to be a bad implementation, in my opinion.

Just to illustrate the potential severity of the problem:

```
var oneMillion = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
                           .Select(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); return x; });

int firstEven = oneMillion.Single(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

The above will output all the integers from 1 to 1000000 before throwing an exception.

It's a head-scratcher for sure.

Comment: +0. While I fully agree with your answer, it basically just repeats what the OP already stated in his question (with the main difference being that you use a much larger collection of integers).

Comment: I disagree: It is Ok, since there are First or FirstOrDefault extension methods already existing in BCL

Comment: @stakx: Ha, yes, good point. Just to give you a sense of where I was coming from: I sometimes interact with developers who, asked a question like this with the OP's example to illustrate, would say: "Yeah? So what? It iterates 5 items unnecessarily; big deal." Why the extrapolation is not something that immediately enters their minds, I can't say. But when I point out what the implications are when taken to the extreme, *then* they "get" it. This answer was aimed at developers like that ;)

Comment: @Artur: I see that you are making this point in many places. I must admit I don't quite understand your logic. The OP was suggesting that `Single` should *throw* after the second match is found. `First` simply *returns* after the first match. This is the main specified behavioral difference between the two methods: one throws, one doesn't. Throwing upon the second found match would maintain this behavior difference but improve the performance of `Single`.

Comment: Single designed to return the single match of a sequence, otherwise the last one, if you will break the look as soon as possible, how would you know if that particular match is the really the last one (until you go to the end)?

Comment: @Artur: You're mistaken about what `Single` is designed to do. It's designed to return the single match, *otherwise throw an exception* — **not** return the last one. Take a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx); nowhere does it say anything about taking the last match. Are you maybe getting `Single` confused with [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I only found this question after filing a report at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/810457/public-static-tsource-single-tsource-this-ienumerable-tsource-source-func-tsource-bool-predicate-doesnt-throw-immediately-on-second-matching-result#

The side-effect argument doesn't hold water, because:

1. Having side-effects isn't really functional, and they're called `Func` for a reason.
2. If you do want side-effects, it makes no more sense to claim the version that has the side-effects throughout the whole sequence is desirable than it does to claim so for the version that throws immediately.
3. It does not match the behaviour of `First` or the other overload of `Single`.
4. It does not match at least some other implementations of `Single`, e.g. Linq2SQL uses `TOP 2` to ensure that only the two matching cases needed to test for more than one match are returned.
5. We can construct cases where we should expect a program to halt, but it does not halt.
6. We can construct cases where `OverflowException` is thrown, which is not documented behaviour, and hence clearly a bug.

Most importantly of all, if we're in a condition where we expected the sequence to have only one matching element, and yet we're not, then something has clearly gone wrong. Apart from the general principle that the only thing you should do upon detecting an error state is clean-up (and this implementation delays that) before throwing, the case of an sequence having more than one matching element is going to overlap with the case of a sequence having more elements in total than expected - perhaps because the sequence has a bug that is causing it to loop unexpectedly. So it's precisely in one possible set of bugs that should trigger the exception, that the exception is most delayed.

Edit:

Peter Lillevold's mention of a repeated test may be a reason why the author chose to take the approach they did, as an optimisation for the non-exceptional case. If so it was needless though, even aside from Eamon Nerbonne showing it wouldn't improve much. There's no need to have a repeated test in the initial loop, as we can just change what we're testing for upon the first match:

```
public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  if(predicate == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
  using(IEnumerator<TSource> en = source.GetEnumerator())
  {
    while(en.MoveNext())
    {
      TSource cur = en.Current;
      if(predicate(cur))
      {
        while(en.MoveNext())
          if(predicate(en.Current))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains more than one matching element");
       return cur;
      }
    }
  }
  throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence contains no matching element");
}
```