# Optimization in the SingleOrDefault function of Linq

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

Here is the code extracted of the SingleOrDefault function:

```
public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) { 
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    TSource result = default(TSource);
    long count = 0; 
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) { 
            result = element; 
            checked { count++; }
        } 
    }
    switch (count) {
        case 0: return default(TSource);
        case 1: return result; 
    }
    throw Error.MoreThanOneMatch(); 
}
```

I'm wondering to know if there is any reason why after finding more than one element in the loop, there is no break statement to prevent looping the rest of the list. In anyways, an error will occurs. For a big list where more than one item is found at the beginning, I think it would make a uge difference.

Comment: Where are you get the code? Decompiled one?

Comment: If you look at the overload not taking a predicate you'll see that it is optimized for IList and only taking two elements. I assume the error case is not important to optimize

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes, I used Resharper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad implementation of Enumerable.Single?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825401/bad-implementation-of-enumerable-single)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jon Skeet [found this while reimplementing LINQ to objects as part of his EduLinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx) :

> It turns out that in LINQ to Objects, the overloads without a predicate throw InvalidOperationException as soon as they see a second element, but the overloads with a predicate keep iterating even when they've seen a second element matching a predicate. This seems ludicrously inconsistent to me - I've opened a Connect issue about it; we'll see what happens.

In the [Connect issue in question](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/639955), Microsft say:

> This would be great to clean up, so that iterating the entire sequence
>   is not required when using the `Single` overload that takes a predicate
>   - we could fail fast upon finding a second match, similar to what we do when no predicate is specified.
>
> However, as the perf benefit to be had here would be limited to
>   `Single`'s error case, this issue currently falls just below our bug
>   triage cut line. We're marking the issue Won't Fix to indicate that
>   we're not currently tracking to fix this issue in the next release of
>   Visual Studio. We'll reactivate this bug over the next year if we get
>   further than expected through our bug triage list, or if we revisit
>   the bug for the following release.

That was in April 2011...